# Difficulty in storing image in the images folder of my project

Tags: asp.net

I want to store images in the root folder of my project.. but the images are getting stored in the admin folder->images. Here's my **C# code**:This code is written in the admin pannel -> AddProducts file..

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = FileImage;
    string virtualFolder = "images/";
    string img = "images/";
    string f = (DateTime.Now.GetHashCode()).ToString(); ;
    string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(physicalFolder + f + FileUpload1.FileName);        
    Image1.Visible = true;
    Image1.ImageUrl = virtualFolder + f + FileUpload1.FileName;
    string path = img + f + FileUpload1.FileName;
    TextBox4.Text = path;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use always `~` symbol whenever use Server.mappath

```
  protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload FileUpload1 = FileImage;
        string virtualFolder = "~/images/";
        string img = "~/images/";
        string f = (DateTime.Now.GetHashCode()).ToString(); ;
        string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(physicalFolder + f + FileUpload1.FileName);
        Image1.Visible = true;
        Image1.ImageUrl = virtualFolder + f + FileUpload1.FileName;
        string path = img + f + FileUpload1.FileName;
        TextBox4.Text = path;
    }
```